# SAML: Differentiate between logout of external Community versus internal user

Tags: customer-community, saml, logout

We have an org + custom developer portal + Customer Community where:

Org does not use `MyDomain`; Community does use custom Domain `forums.foo.com`

```
   # TYPE OF USER    LOGIN TARGET                            LOGIN MECHANISM
   1 Internal        Sales/Service Cloud                     login.salesforce.com
   2 Internal        Customer Community                      Global header
   3 Internal        Developer Portal/Customer Community     SSO via in-house IdP
   4 External        Developer Portal/Customer Community     SSO via in-house IdP
```

We're using Federated SSO; internal users have FederationIds to support use case #3

*NOTE that SSO is not used to login to Sales/Service Cloud; only the Customer Community.*

*NOTE Salesforce is the Service Provider in use case 3 and 4*

**Goal:**

- When user logged in via IdP, Logout should go back to IdP login page
- When user logged in via `login.salesforce.com`, Logout should go back to `login.salesforce.com`

**Equally valid, acceptable goal:**

- If internal user, logout goes to `login.salesforce.com`
- If external user, logout goes to IdP login page

We have a custom Logout URL in the SSO setup:  `myIdp.foo.com/saml/logout`

When the SSO custom logout page is reached, what we have observed is the HTTP header referrer property (in PROD) is always the same regardless of use case:

```
   # TYPE OF USER    LOGOUT VIA                            REFERRER
   1 Internal        Sales/Service Cloud Logout            naXX.salesforce.com                    login.salesforce.com
   2 Internal        Customer Community Logout             naXX.salesforce.com
   3 Internal        Customer Community Logout             naXX.salesforce.com
   4 External        Customer Community Logout             naXX.salesforce.com
```

**Options considered:**

1. We had hoped that if the logout came from the Community `forums.foo.com`, that the HTTP header referrer would be that domain but it isn't.
2. Merge fields like `$User.UserType` aren't allowed in SSO custom logout URLs.

**So, since Logout is always going to the custom SSO/IdP logout page, how do we tell it from whence the logout occurred so we can redirect to the relevant login page?**

Comment: I think you'd have to use multiple SAML endpoints to differentiate. As far as I know, if there's a logout URL, it is always used, regardless if the login is IdP- or SP-initiated.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I'm not sure I follow your suggestion.  Use cases 1 and 2 don't even start with SAML SSO so what would be the SAML endpoint to configure? How would SFDC know which SSO config to use?